# Detecting different string literals using templates in C++

Tags: c++, c++20

I was playing with templates to detect different string literals and I came to following code (try it with C++20):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, const char*>, int> = 0>
void print_str(T) {
    std::cout << "char* print_str\n";
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, const char8_t*>, int> = 0>
void print_str(T) {
    std::cout << "char8_t* print_str\n";
}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, const wchar_t*>, int> = 0>
void print_str(T) {
    std::cout << "wchar_t* print_str\n";
}

int main() {
    auto a = "hello"; // prints "char* print_str"
    print_str(a);
    auto b = L"hello"; // prints "wchar_t* print_str"
    print_str(b);
    auto c = u8"hello"; // prints "char8_t* print_str"
    print_str(c);
}
```

I use the fact that in C++20, the `u8` prefix declares `char8_t` type. But here are my questions:

1. Even though `u8` prefix is from C++11, it uses `char8_t` only starting C++20. So how I can detect UTF-8 strings which is prefixed with `u8` between C++11 and C++20?
2. How I can change my templates to detect both for example `const char*` and `char*` which same function? I tried to use `remove_const<>` but it does not work because it won't remove `const` from `const char*`.

Comment: "here are my questions" - Please stick to *one* question per Stackowerflow post.

Comment: If `remove_const<>` removed `const` from your `const char *`, what would you expect to be able to do with it? You cannot modify a constant.

Comment: For your second question you can just add a `|| std::is_same_v<...` for the the `char*` types.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I wanted to generalize template so the function work for non-literal strings too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can't detect `char8_t` in languages like C++17 that did not have it. So you have to have constexpr function that detects if it is UTF-8 by examining contents of the string. Such function makes sense with `char8_t` also. It is simple to construct illegal UTF-8 strings using `char8_t`. C++17 or less did not contain such functions.
2. Use or? `std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, const char*> || std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<T>, char*>`

Comment: I'm not proficient in templates yet, so I forgot I can use `||`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. So how I can detect UTF-8 strings which is prefixed with u8 between C++11 and C++20?

Type of string doesn't ensure encoding.

`const char*` can be used for utf-8 but also for LATIN-1
In the same way `const wchar*` is not necessary utf-16.

There is some heuristic to detect encoding.

> 2. How I can change my templates to detect both for example const char* and char* which same function? I tried to use `remove_const<>` but it does not work because it won't remove `const` from `const char*`.

`const char *` != `char* const`.

You can remove `const` from the later to obtain `char*`

You might do

```
std::is_same_v<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>, char> && std::is_pointer_v<T>
```

but simply change to:

```
void print_str(const char*) { std::cout << "char* print_str\n"; }
void print_str(const char8_t*) { std::cout << "char8_t* print_str\n"; }
void print_str(const wchar_t*) { std::cout << "wchar_t* print_str\n"; }
```

If you insist with template:

```
template <typename T>
void print_str(const T*) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<char, T>) {
        std::cout << "char* print_str\n";
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<char8_t, T>) {
        std::cout << "char8_t* print_str\n";
    } else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<wchar_t, T>) {
        std::cout << "wchar_t* print_str\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that that type of string does not ensure encoding. But I wanted to somehow differentiate between normal string and `u8` string and throw exception if `u8` is not UTF-8. So I could have a function that print UTF-8 string (if it really is) only if it is started with `u8`.